# Plotly iFrame in Vue is being resized with display:none

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, plotly-python, plotly.js

I'm trying to display different Plotly charts on different tabs using vuetify. In each tab I would like to display a plotly chart that I'm embedding into an iFrame. This works fine for the first diplayed graph (aka iFrame), however Plotly has an issue if it loads while the display: none (which will occur on every other tab). Is there a way I can either load the iframe before display: none from the current div, or maybe there is an easy way to reload the iframe when I switch to that tab? I've tried explicitly setting the width in px (almost anywhere I can) as described here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2769

```
      <template>
      <v-card>
          <v-toolbar flat color="primary" dark>
            <v-toolbar-title>Plotly Charts</v-toolbar-title>
          </v-toolbar>
          <v-tabs
            v-model="tab"
            background-color="primary"
            dark
          >
            <v-tab
               v-for="item in items"
               :key="item.tab"
            >
              {{ item.tab }}
            </v-tab>
            <v-tabs-items v-model="tab" style="width:2100px;">
              <v-tab-item
                v-for="item in items"
                :key="item.tab"
                style="width:2100px;"
              >
                  <iframe scrolling="yes" style="border:none; display: unset" @load="load" seamless="seamless" :src="item.value + '?width=2100'" height="5000" width="2100"></iframe>
              </v-tab-item>
            </v-tab-items>
          </v-tabs>
        </v-card>
    </template>
    <script>
export default {
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      tab: null,
      items: [
        {tab: 'Chart1', value: "chart1.html"},
        {tab: 'Chart2', value: "chart2.html"},
        {tab: 'Chart3', value: "chart3.html"},
      ],
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```